# how to attach delimiter to the scraped table?

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

very new to coding, i apologise if i'm being silly but very keen to learn. 
I'm scraping a webpage(https://www.myinsuranceclub.com/health-insurance/star-health-network-hospital-list) using selenium by extracting table rows as shown in the code below. Could some one guide me on how I could add a delimiter to each element?
the motive is to save the table in the CSV format seperating : name;;address;;city;;state;;pincode

```
# find_elements_by_xpath returns an array of selenium objects.
total = 302
j=1
while(j <= total):
    i = 1
    while(i <= 25):
        titles_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='hospital_all']/tbody/tr[{}]".format(i))
        i += 1
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
        titles = [x.text for x in titles_element]
    # print out all the titles.
        print('titles:')
        print(titles, '\n')
        sys.stdout = open("data.txt", "a")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hospital_all_next"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    j+=1
```

current output: 
titles:
['Srinivasa Nursing Home Beside Natraj Talkies Adilabad Andhra Pradesh 504001'] 
titles:
['Padmasri Hospitals # 49-48 - 16/5 Nggos Colony Near Roc Petrol Bunk Akkayyapalem Andhra Pradesh 530016']

expected output:
titles:
['Srinivasa Nursing Home;; Beside Natraj Talkies;; Adilabad;; Andhra Pradesh;; 504001'] 
titles:
['Padmasri Hospitals;; # 49-48 - 16/5 Nggos Colony Near Roc Petrol Bunk;; Akkayyapalem;; Andhra Pradesh;; 530016']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join but as you are using a list comprehension isn't it a list anyway with "," between elements?

```
 titles = ';;'.join([x.text for x in titles_element])
```

python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.myinsuranceclub.com/health-insurance/star-health-network-hospital-list')

rows =  WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hospital_all tr.odd, #hospital_all tr.even")))

for row in rows:
    soup = bs(row.get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'lxml')
    titles = ';;'.join([x.text for x in soup.select('td')])
    pos = titles[:-2].rfind(";;")
    titles = titles[:-2][:pos] + ' ' + titles[:-2][pos+2:]
    print(titles)
```

Comment: the output doesn't come with a delimiter. using this 
""titles = ';;'.join([x.text for x in titles_element])"" 
doesn't add the delimiter either. after running the above code the 
new output is 
titles:
Srinivasa Nursing Home Beside Natraj Talkies Adilabad Andhra Pradesh 504001 

titles:
Padmasri Hospitals # 49-48 - 16/5 Nggos Colony Near Roc Petrol Bunk Akkayyapalem Andhra Pradesh 530016  

expected output:
titles:
Srinivasa Nursing;; Home Beside Natraj Talkies;; Adilabad;; Andhra Pradesh 504001

Comment: You can use replace to get rid of last ;; if you don't want it for the last two elements: Andhra Pradesh;;504001